# Swift: repetitive try catch code

Tags: swift

I want to create a snippet for try/catch error handling:

```
static func tryCatch(block: (Void) -> Void)  -> Any? {
    var result: Any?
    do {
        result = try block()
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error) //TODO: write error to log
    }
    return result
}
```

but when I call my snippet I get an error from compiler: 
Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

```
player = Common.tryCatch {
            AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: selectedSoundURL!)
        } as? AVAudioPlayer
```

Is there a way to reuse try/catch code so that I don't have to write the same code for logging my errors?

Comment: You can put all your try {} at one do{ }catch{}, it would work just fine

Comment: You should take a look at `try?`. It pretty much entirely removes the need for this

Comment: Also, avoid writing classes like `Common`. This isn't `Java` or `C#`. You're not limited to putting all your methods into static classes with arbitrary names

Comment: @Alexander: Only without the error logging.

Comment: I want to re-use this code in different controllers

Comment: @MartinR Oh true, you can check for `nil`, but you lose the error object

Comment: Also note that `Void` is a typealias for `()`, so using `(Void)` as the parameter list translates to `(())`. Just say `() -> Void`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `block` parameter must be marked as `throw`ing:

```
func tryCatch<T>(block: () throws -> T) -> T? {
    do {
        return  try block()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Using a generic function instead of `Any` makes the type
casts redundant.

As @Hamish correctly said, you still have to call the throwing function 
with `try`, e.g.

```
let player = tryCatch {
    try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: selectedSoundURL!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indicate that the block you are passing in can throw:

`func tryCatch(block: (Void) throws -> Void) -> Any? {`